# show initial value on spinner other than first value in adapter?

Tags: android

i have to display a spinner ,it is getting its content from adapter at run time . when spinner appear on screen Select a value should appear on it instead of first value in adapter.Please help

Comment: spinner contain list of items say milk,bread etc...select product should appear on spinner instead of first item i.e milk.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a particular item in your collection to be selected have a look at:
[Spinner.setSelection(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Then You have to add that text at first position in you string array.

```
   Spinner rangeSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.rangeSpinner);
   String[] items = new String[] {"Select Product","Bread","Milk"};
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.custom_spinner_textview_layout, items);
   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   rangeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

### custom_spinner_textview_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18.0sp"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_text"
        android:gravity="left"/>
```

[image]

Comment: i don't want this..when the spinner appears on screen its showing first value as default value on spinner that i don't want.I want spinner should show select an item rather than first item contained in adapter.In pic posted by u spinner will show "regular" when spinner will appear on screen , I want it to display "select Type".

Answer (score 0):

****Just try It fri...****

### 1.String[] _Purchesedlistarray = { "Required", "purchased" };

2.ArrayAdapter Purchesedadapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, _Purchesedlistarray);
        Purchesedadapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

### _PurchesedSpinner.setAdapter(Purchesedadapter);

3._PurchesedSpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

```
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Appsconstent._Purchesed = parent.getItemAtPosition(
                            position).toString();
                    System.out.println("the Value is--------------->"
                            + Appsconstent._Purchesed);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
```